# Passing File Path From Javascript to C# Using Ajax Web Service

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have an ASP.Net website with buttons who pass a file path to a javascript function that executes an ajax call to a web method.  The file path you see being passed to openDoc below is the result of JSON.stringify(\fs01\Documents...)

```
  <input type="button" id="b0" value="Open" onclick="openDoc('&quot;\\\\fs01\\Documents\\2011\\MEASEJA\\1108030203&nbsp;(1)&nbsp;10-3-2011&nbsp;Mart&nbsp;Cart&nbsp;Service&nbsp;Completion&nbsp;Survey.pdf&quot;');">

    function openDoc(filename) {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("POST", "Default.aspx", true);
    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xml.readyState == 4) {
            if (xml.status == 200) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "Service.asmx/openDoc",
                    data: '{ file:' + filename + '}',
                    success: function () { },
                    error: function (xml, status, error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xml.responseText + ")");
                        alert("Open Doc: " + xml.Message);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    xml.send(null);
}

[WebMethod]
public byte[] openDoc(string file)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer;

    try
    {
        int length = (int)fs.Length;
        buffer = new byte[length];
        int count;
        int sum = 0;

        while ((count = fs.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
            sum += count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();   
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Problem is, somewhere along the way, something is happening to the \ in the file path and receiving errors like this from the ajax call using firebug:

"Unrecognized escape sequence. (16): { file:"\fs01\Documents\2011\MEASEJA\1108030203 (1) 10-3-2011 Mart Cart Service Completion Survey.pdf"}"

I know that in C# you have to double up all the \, but that is how the file path began from the button click.  Somewhere along the line, I am losing the additional \'s and C# can't process it as a file.

Answer (score 0):

try looking for a single backslash and doubling if needed

```
//pseudocode
if (s.StartsWith(@"\f")) s.Prepend(@"\");
```

Comment: Before I pass it as a parameter to ajax?

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  Now that I look closely I know what you're going for.  I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Added if (file.StartsWith(@"\f")) { file = @"\" + file; } to the beginning of the web method but I get the same error.